# Can't access root folder in File Explorer since installing Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: permissions, 22.04, root, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using WSL and I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 and I can no longer access the root folder under that directory. I can access the root folder in my OLD ubuntu directory, but when I click on root under Ubuntu 22.04, it does absolutely nothing, and if I try to copy anything into there, I get an error that says Permission Required. Can anyone help me?

I'm kind of a newbie so if there's any additional information you need, please let me know!